# Efficient way to parse code symbols from a string to build enum array

Tags: c#, enums

I get data from a remote device that sends numerical data with status strings that contain single-letter codes.
I need to map all the single-character status codes in the string into corresponding enum values and put these enum values into a property, which the class consumer can then call to understand the status without having to look up the single-character status codes. An example status string is "...Q.D..B".

Is there a pattern that does this without the use of a huge switch statement or multiple if statements?

Note: The code actually contains over twenty statuses, but I have edited them out for brevity.

```
[Flags]
public enum DataQuality
{
    Good = 0x0001,                           
    Questionable = 0x0004,                  
    NotCorrected = 0x0008,             
    BadEstimatedValue = 0x0010        
}

public class DataPointStatus
{
    private const string Good = "...";
    private const char Questionable = 'Q';
    private const char NotCorrected = 'D';
    private const char BadEstimatedValue = 'B';
    // Lot's more statuses...

    private readonly string _rawStatus;
    private readonly List<DataQuality> _statuses = new List<DataQuality>();

    public DataPointStatus(string rawStatus)
    {
        if (rawStatus == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"'{nameof(rawStatus)}' cannot be null.");
        }

        if (rawStatus.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(rawStatus)}' cannot be an empty string.");
        }

        _rawStatus = rawStatus;

        SetStatusToGoodIfDataHasNoQualityErrors();
        if (!IsGood) SetBadQualityStatuses();
    }

    public bool IsGood => _statuses.Any(x => x == DataQuality.Good);
    public IEnumerable<DataQuality> Statuses => _statuses;

    private void CheckForGoodStatus()
    {
        if (_rawStatus == Good)
        {
            _statuses.Add(DataQuality.Good);
        }
    }

    private void SetStatusToGoodIfDataHasNoQualityErrors()
    {
        string status = _rawStatus.Replace(".", string.Empty);

        Start:
        switch (status)
        {
            case string s when s == "": return;

            case string s when s.Contains(Questionable):
                _statuses.Add(DataQuality.Questionable);
                status = status.Trim(Questionable);
                goto Start;

            case string s when s.Contains(NotCorrected):
                _statuses.Add(DataQuality.NotCorrected);
                status = status.Trim(NotCorrected);
                goto Start;

            case string s when s.Contains(BadEstimatedValue):
                _statuses.Add(DataQuality.BadEstimatedValue);
                status = status.Trim(BadEstimatedValue);
                goto Start;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    $"Invalid status code.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you need? It's not clear.

Comment: Enum.Parse? With a Ling Select It should be enought

Comment: @ downVoter Is the question more clear now?

Answer (score 1):

You could store enum in dictionary:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, DataQuality>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    ["G"] = DataQuality.Good,
    ["Q"] = DataQuality.Questionable,
    ["N"] = DataQuality.NotCorrected,
    ["B"] = DataQuality.BadEstimatedValue
};
string input = "Q";
if (dic.TryGetValue(input, out var status))
{
    // Use "status" variable here
}
```

Comment: I did a poor job asking question. I need to input something like "Q...B..D" and convert these single-letter codes to enums by steppting through all the characters in the string. All of the statuses as enums are then put in an array. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to find statuses

```
//Regular expression can be more elaborated, 
//searching the status char in a concrete part of the string and so on
Regex regex = new Regex("Q|D|B");
```

And then a dictionary to match the string value with the correponding flag value

```
Dictionary<string, DataQuality> qualities = InitializeDictionary();
```

This whould be placed in a loop. Somthing like `while (rawStatus != "")`:

```
Match match = regex.Match(rawStatus);
if (match.Success) {
    _statuses.Add(qualities[match.Value]);
    rawStatus = regex.Replace(rawStatus, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not be directly applicable to your code, as you need the Flag.
For the parsing a string to a list of Enum Value you can use a char Enum :

```
Enum MyEnum
{
    Good = 'g',
    Questionable = 'q',
    NotCorrected = 'n',
    BadEstimatedValue = 'b'
    //[...]
}
```

You can use [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert a string to his enum value.
But for a char a simple cast `(MyEnum)myChar` is enought.
This will convert all char to int value, even if they are not defined in the enum.
 [Enum.IsDefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) will indicate if it exist in a specified enumeration.

For a char enum:

```
var input = "qngb###qnga";
var result = input.Where(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(toto), (int)x))
                  .Select(x => (toto)x);
```

Result:

> Questionable
>   NotCorrected
>   Good
>   BadEstimatedValue
>   Questionable
>   NotCorrected
>   Good

Comment: I did not realize that enums could be equated to a char. That may prove useful. Thank you.

Comment: Carefully on Enum Char if you use Flag. Because the result could be Strange, because G+Q will be 119 W.